Github Action Logs
I have integrated playwright zephyr reporter and run my tests using github actions.
I use https://github.com/elaichenkov/playwright-zephyr plugin and it prints following logs in console.
In next step I would like to grab link to test cycle from my console log that you can see below and send it teams notification.
My question is how to get this link and store it as variable that i can use in next step.


Try saving the logs into a file using npx playwright test > test_op.log. In the next step parse the file and get the URL you want and store in an environment variable.

Looks like you can use reporters feature and dump the results to a file. See JSON reporter. With JSON output file, you can use jq to extract what you need from the report. (Not tested)
